# Issue importing database to database project in Visual Studio

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, database-project

I have created a dev database in SQL Server and added a table in SSMS. I have created a .NET 6 application and created the database project and data project and now I am trying to import the database.

When I click select connection, it can find the database, if I select the Windows authentication option, it looks like it worked, but then the start button is greyed out.

If I select SQL Server authentication and try to use the login I have set up as `db_owner` in SSMS, I get this error:

> Login failed 18456

I can login fine in SSMS as that login.

I am now stuck as to whether this is an issue with how I have set up the database and login user or whether this is an issue in Visual Studio. Please help!

I have checked that the login is set up as `db_owner` and `systemadmin` which it is.

I have also changed the default connection database for that user to the database rather than default or master.

Comment: Important note, a `LOGIN` and `USER` are separate objects in SQL Server. You can't give a `LOGIN` the *database* role `db_owner`, because `LOGIN`s are server objects; you would give the `USER` in the database that is linked to the `LOGIN` the `db_owner` role. As for the authentication error, have you checked the SQL Server's logs? That will give you a much more verbose error reason, as authentication errors passed back to the application layer are intentionally vague.

Comment: Have you checked the instance's ERRORLOG for the 18456 error events? Take note of the State number that's shown there and check it against the State numbers listed at [MSSQLSERVER_18456](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/errors-events/mssqlserver-18456-database-engine-error) to determine the cause.